# What to do when geoQuery does not output data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am using GeoFire to read location data in Firebase and then add it to a Google map.

When I run the `GeoQueryDataEventListener ()` method, depending on the center and the radius set, it does not produce any results (and it is fine that it is because I do not have information loaded for those parameters).

Then, when this happens, I would like an alert to be issued for the user to change the search radius (for example).

In what part of the `GeoQueryDataEventListener ()` method should I insert the alert? I was testing with all the sub-methods but with none I succeeded.

I leave the code that I have written:

```
private void leerUbicaciones() {

    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(userLatitude, userLongitude), radio);

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
            final String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("location/" + key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .snippet(dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class))
                            .title(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class))
                            .draggable(false)
                            .position(new LatLng(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class), dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class))));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.v("TAG", "onCancelled");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataExited(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("TAG", "onDataExited");

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.v("TAG", "onDataMoved");


        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.v("TAG", "onDataChanged");

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            Log.v("TAG", "onGeoQueryReady");

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.v("TAG", "onGeoQueryError");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The first thing is to check if your `onDataEntered` gets called, either by adding a `Log.v("TAG", "onDataEntered");` statement as the first line inside it or by running the code in a debugger and putting a breakpoint on the first line inside it.

Comment: I checked it, but without results the onDataEntered method is not called.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. You'll want to use `onGeoQueryReady` to detect when the query is done. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a geoquery `onDataEntered` immediately fires for each node within the range. When `onDataEntered` has been called for all nodes, your `onGeoQueryReady` is called to signal that the initial results for the query have been processed.

If another node enters the query range afterwards, your `onDataEntered` will also fire. After `onDataEntered` has been called for all nodes entering the range, again your `onGeoQueryReady` is called to signal the end of the update.